# What happens to auto renewal subscriptions when the app is deleted from the device?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

For instance: If a user has deleted app from his iOS device and he has subscribed to a auto renewal feature in the same app. Then Apple auto stop the auto renewal or would it continue to renew product subscription ?

Answer (score 3):

The auto renewal subscription is linked to the users AppleID and not to your App. So it will be renewed until the user explicitly cancels the subscription in the App Store settings. Deleting your app does not change the subscription status.